# How to use user-defined function in another Program

Tags: path, include, visual-studio-code, user-defined-functions

How to use user-defined modules in my Program, im using VSCODE and added the path to user-defined module path but when i #include<> them and use them debugger shows me error "No such file or directory " .

[here is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofYSb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `Prime` file has no file extension. Be sure that you have a valid `Prime.h` and `Prime.cpp` file. Then include your `.h` file like this:

```cpp
#include "./Path/To/Prime/Prime.h"
```